# Добавление https на localhost

Tags: node.js, ssl

у меня есть клиентская и серверная часть, все задеплоил на сервер и запустил, все работает, но почему то та же вариация с localhost ругается на сертификаты безопасности, а в интернетах все работает, сертификаты открываются и рабочие, в чем загвоздка?

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express()

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./certificates/privkey.pem', 'utf8')
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('./certificates/fullchain.pem', 'utf8')

const credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate }

const server = https.createServer(credentials, app)
const io = socketIo(server, {
  path: '/api/messages',
})

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
  })
)
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/api', router)
app.use(errorMiddleware)

io.on('connection', (socket) => handleWebSocketConnection(socket, io))

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {})
    server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on PORT = ${PORT}`))
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

start()
```

```
node:internal/tls/secure-context:92
  context.setKey(key, passphrase);
          ^

Error: PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey
```

Comment: Нужно смотреть на что именно ругается (в любой непонятной ситуации нужно читать что в ошибке написано). Вероятно, ругается что домен (localhost) не соответствует домену, к которому относится сертификат.

Comment: @insolor ну по ошибке я снизу написал - это все что выдает, но скорей всего именно ваш вариант, не подумал(

Comment: Ну тут не понятно. Я не видел текст ошибки, т.к. он был в коде ниже прокрутки, предположил, что ошибка в браузере, а тут похоже что ошибка на бэкэнде.

Comment: Какие версии nodejs и OpenSSL на сервере и на локальной машине?